# How to override an environment entry?

Tags: java, tomcat

In our software we have this in the web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
<description>Whether or not to use cache in the calc engine.  Typically true for web services, false for Vertex Central.</description>
<env-entry-name>CalcEngineUseCache</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-value>false</env-entry-value>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
```

Is overriding this simply passing -DCalcEngineUseCache=true to the JAVA_OPTS?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html#Resource_Definitions), `<env-entry>` it's a JNDI environment entry. -Dxxx are on the system environment area so they are on a different context.

> The name of the environment entry to be created, relative to the java:comp/env context.